# Stop the thread from inside the target function?

Tags: python, multithreading

Is there a way that I can stop the thread after few seconds (INTERNALLY)

```
t1 = Thread(target=call_script1, args=())
t2 = Thread(target=call_script2, args=())
t3 = Thread(target=call_script3, args=())

t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()
t3.join()
```

The Main program waits until thread returns. I would like to know if there is a way - when I spawn a thread - say t2, it targets a function - call_script2. Lets say that function takes like 5 seconds to run completely. I would like to know if I can return the thread say like after 3 seconds.

The ability of the thread to return after 3 seconds should be inside the call_script2 function. I believe having stop_event.wait(3) in the main thread does not work.

call_script2 function looks something like this.

```
def InterfaceThread2():
    a = 1;
    d = 2
    i = 1
    while i ==1:
        #ser = serial.Serial(3, 115200)
        if ser.isOpen():
            ser.write('\x5A\x03\x02\x00\x02\x07')

            a = ser.read(7) #### THIS COMMAND WAITS UNTIL IT RECEIVES DATA FROM MCU
            ## This usually happens in 100ms in theory. If it is taking like more than 100ms -for safety say I will wait for three seconds and if it did not respond back
            ## I want to stop the thread and popup an error message.

        # Tell the GUI about the Information
        wx.CallAfter(pub.sendMessage, "APP_EVENT2", arg1 = a, arg2 = d)
        print "hello"

        time.sleep(1)
        i = i+1
```

Comment: On what condition do you decide whether to exit the thread after 3 seconds versus letting it finish?

Comment: The target function  call_script2 - calls for serial communication with a MCU. The MCU takes like 100ms to reply back - when requested to read. So I would like to wait say 3 secs, if the MCU did not reply - stop the thread - pop up an error message

Comment: And the response controls whether to continue or exit? What is supposed to happen from the time of the response until the 3 seconds? This may be easier if you post the `call_script2` code.

Comment: Is it possible to interrupt the MCU API call? If not, you're not going to be able to make the thread exit before the API returns.

Comment: Basically, wait until 3 seconds for data from serial communication. If you get data in less than 3 seconds. Finish the thread. If not wait until 3 seconds and pop up an error message saying - MCU did not respond back properly - SOmething is wrong. I edited the question.

Comment: I think this is more of a question about serial timeouts. If you set the serial timeout to 3 seconds and then try to read from it, either it will return the data or it will raise a timeout exception. Then if the timeout exception was raised, `return` from the target, otherwise, handle the data. Is that what you are looking to do?

Comment: The `serial.Serial` object support a [`timeout`](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial) parameter, which you can use to set a max waiting period for reads to complete.

Comment: If you use that you would need to check the number of bytes written to ensure you got all the data you wanted back, since when the timeout expires, the call just returns whatever bytes it received so far, rather than raising an exception.

Comment: @FamousJameous I looked into it. I have an another thread - which is targetted at a different function - say call_script3 - but using the same serial port. This thread is a long running task. It has to run like 30 minutes. So I am not sure, if I set ser.timeout - I will interrupt that ! That thread will basically does the same function but read data every 1 second continuously.

Comment: @JeshKundem Can you use a separate `Serial` instance per-thread?

Comment: @Dano - I am illeterate on how that would work - both threads have to use the same serial port. If I say -according to you ---- ser_new = serial.Serial(3,115200), I have no clue about effects of using this instance in parallel with my original "ser" instance. Wont they confuse when reading data?

Comment: If the other thread is reading data every 1 second, it shouldn't ever time out. The timeout applies to transactions on the serial port, not to connections.

Comment: @JeshKundem I guess I'm confused - you're talking about having two different threads read from the same serial instance now. How do they not get confused?

Comment: @Dano -  No, I am talkign about using different "ser" instances for two different threads. Say "ser1" and "ser2". But both the instances are from a specific serial port which is COM4 in my case. Wont these two instances get confused when reading data from the MCU?

Comment: @JeshKundem Sorry, what I mean is in your current code, you have multiple threads sharing the same `ser` instance. How do those threads not step on each other? Do you guarantee that none of them will write/read at the same time?

Comment: @Dano I still have to figure that out man. They might step on each other. But currently I gave time.sleep(1). I cant guarantee it they wont interfere - especially with same serial instance. I cant even use threading lock because they are two different target functions. If you can come up with a solution I will mark your answer.

Comment: You can definitely use `threading.Lock` to guarantee two functions won't use the connection at the same time. In any case, I think @FamousJameous when he said you can still use the `timeout` parameter of the `Serial` constructor - its a timeout for each read operation. There's never a case where you expect a read to take 3 or more seconds, right? So its safe to use that timeout for your shared `Serial` instance. You just need to make sure your code validates the number of bytes it gets back after every read, to make sure you got all the data you expect back.

Comment: How would one can use same lock for two different threads calling two different target functions.  This would eliminate my problem of threads stepping on each other. A lock object is specific to a target function. I cant use the same lock object to a differnet target function

Comment: @JeshKundem Sure you can - just pass the `Lock` instance into both functions.

Comment: Something like this?Create a lock object in the main function and call the InstanceThread as follows. 
def InstanceThread(Lock)  : Inside the function...I say lock.acquire() # do stuff and lock.release? I believe it wont suffice what I am looking for because - I have a while loop in one of the functions to run the continuous thread.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122539/discussion-between-jesh-kundem-and-dano).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get the behavior you want by using the `timeout` parameter available on the `serial.Serial()` constructor. Additionally, you'll need to protect your interactions with the `Serial` instance with a `threading.Lock()`, so that your threads don't step on each other as they read/write data:

```
ser = serial.Serial(..., timeout=3, ...)
lock = Threading.Lock()

def call_script1():
    a = 1
    d = 2
    i = 1
    while i == 1:  # Lock is acquired here
        with lock:
            if ser.isOpen():
                ser.write('\x5A\x03\x02\x00\x02\x07')
                a = ser.read(7)
                if len(a) != 7:
                    # We didn't get all the bytes we wanted, a timeout
                    # must have occurred.
                    print("Only read {} bytes!".format(len(a)))
                    # Maybe exit or throw an exception?

        # Lock is released here.
        # Tell the GUI about the Information
        wx.CallAfter(pub.sendMessage, "APP_EVENT2", arg1 = a, arg2 = d)
        print "hello"

        time.sleep(1)
        i = i+1

def call_script2():
    while i == 1:
        with lock:
            if ser.isOpen():
                # Do whatever

def call_script3():
    while i == 1:
        with lock:
            if ser.isOpen():
                # Do whatever

t1 = Thread(target=call_script1, args=())
t2 = Thread(target=call_script2, args=())
t3 = Thread(target=call_script3, args=())

t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()
t3.join()
```

Comment: One of those call_script functions in my program is an infinite while loop. If it acquires the lock, it wont release it

Comment: @JeshKundem You can acquire/release it *inside* the loop. Imagine if `call_script1()` above used `while True:` instead of `while i == 1:`. It would still release the lock right after it finishes reading 7 bytes (or the read times out), update the GUI, sleep for one second, then try to acquire the lock again.

Comment: Thank yoU DANO for educating me.

Answer (score 0):

The [`Thread.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread) method has an optional `timeout` parameter.

```
# block until thread ``t`` completes, or just wait 3 seconds
t.join(3)
```

If you want the target function to handle this logic of timing out, I suggest writing a wrapper to spawn a new thread, make the call, then join with a 3-second timeout.

```
from threading import Thread
import time

def counter(limit):
    for i in range(limit):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(0.1)

timeout = 3
def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    t = Thread(target=counter, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    t.join(timeout)

t = Thread(target=wrapper, args=(100,))
t.start()
t.join()
```

Note that this doesn't actually kill the subthread until the main process dies. Killing a thread without knowing what it's doing inside could cause all sorts of mess.

If you can change the code of the original functions, you can have them periodically poll to check if anyone wants them dead.

Edit: Looks like I somewhat misunderstood the question. It was more about how to use PySerial to share 1 open `Serial` object across 3 workers, with a timeout on reads from the serial port.

Comment: That won't actually cancel the thread, it'll just stop the thread you called `join()` in from blocking until it completes.

Comment: Good point. We can make it a ``daemon`` thread, but it'll still keep going until the main process dies.